# What is the fastest way of finding all longest matches in a string given a large set of key patterns?

Tags: python, string, pattern-matching, string-matching

I have a set of patterns (substrings) and I need to find out all longest matches in any given string. Now I can only think of an approach with regular expression in which patterns are sorted by length reversely and then concatenated:

```
import re
pattern_set = {pattern_0, pattern_1, ..., pattern_n}
pattern_list = sorted(list(pattern_set), key=len, reverse=True)
pattern = r'(%s)' % '|'.join(pattern_list)
matches = re.findall(pattern, string)
```

But I think this approach is a bit primitive and it should cost more time as the pattern set grows in size. I wonder if there is a better approach. How are such kind of tasks usually done in industry?

Comment: Are the individual patterns exact strings or regular expressions themselves?

Comment: Exact strings. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Are you concerned (more) about the time to preprocess the patterns or to search large/numerous strings afterwards?

Comment: I think the latter is more important. How do they make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [rure](https://github.com/davidblewett/rure-python) which is much better at optimizing alternations (`|`) than Python's built-in regex engine, by using finite-state machines.